# Changing facet_wrap Graph Titles for Survival Curves

Tags: r, ggplot2, survival-analysis, facet-wrap

I have 5 survival curves I currently need to format for a research paper. The code for my survivorship function is below.

```
all<-survfit(Surv(MD,Censor)~DepTyp,data=add,conf.type='log-log')
```

From the code above, I generate 5 survival curves, and I would like to use ggplot's facet_wrap to and structure them. My code ggplot code is:

```
sg<-summary(all) 
ggplot()+geom_line(all,mapping=aes(x=time,y=surv))+facet_wrap(sg$strata,ncol=2)
```

Where sg is a summary of the each survival curve. My problem is trying to change the titles of the faceted survival curves. Currently, each curve is titled like "Title=A". I want to change each title to their formal names, ie "Female". I used the labeller functions, but had no luck, and I'm assuming its because of the way the strata is factored. I could use the ggsurvplot function, but I like the way the facet looks, I just need to change the titles. Is there anyway I can do this or do I need to use a different graphing package?

Comment: can you post the structure of `add` by posting the results of `dput(add)` or if that's too large `dput(head(add))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to use `labeller` to modify facet label text. Another way is to modify the data to change the labels of `strata` variable. 
Since I do not have your survival data, I use `diab_df` data from `chest` as an example:

```r
library(survival)
library(ggplot2)
library(chest)  # example data diab_df
# Fit model 
all <- survfit(Surv(t0, t1,Endpoint) ~ Sex, 
             data =diab_df,conf.type='log-log')
all <- broom::tidy(all)

# Original plot
ggplot(data = all, aes(x = time, y = estimate))+
  geom_line()+ 
facet_wrap(.~strata)
```

[image]

```r
# Solution 1: 
stratalabs <- c("Male", "Female")
names(stratalabs) <- c("Sex=1", "Sex=2")
ggplot(data = all, aes(x = time, y = estimate))+
  geom_line()+ 
  facet_wrap( .~ strata, labeller = labeller(strata = stratalabs))
```

[image]

```r
# Solution 2: 
all$strata = factor(all$strata, levels = c("Sex=1", "Sex=2"), 
                   labels = c("Male", "Female"))
ggplot(data = all, aes(x = time, y = estimate))+
  geom_line() + 
  facet_wrap( .~ strata)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-01-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This is perfect, both solutions work perfectly, thank you for very much.